# Can we change Community Template Background dynamically?

Tags: visualforce, community, css, customer-community, style

I am trying to achieve `Account` specific branding in Communities. So every user belonging to one account sees a specific background. Preferably, the background-image needs to be related to the account record.

I tried using the Edit CSS option in the community Theme settings. Below option:
[image]

The backgroud css can be applied here, but it can be only one static image URL. Like, I have uploaded the image in documents and made it externally available. The background image is reflected.

I want this to be dynamic, which I am not able to achieve. Is this possible? Or any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is a thing called "Page Variations". You can create audiences and show them different variations of the page (including a different template)

This might still be hard to achieve, but it should be possible to do something similar to what you are wanting, albeit with limits.

[image]

In the variation, you can specify things such as profile, and specifically, the Account on a user:

[image]

See at the bottom of the image, you have the ability to specify the AccountId.

I have not used this feature yet, so you will need to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do something like this would be to use the `Experience Id`. Unfortunately to access the `expid`, you would likely need to set up [Dynamic Branding URLs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_dynamic.htm&type=0) for login. You can learn more about this Identity feature by reading [Dynamic Branding for Multiple Brands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_dynamic_multiple_brands.htm) in the Salesforce Identity Implementation Guide.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't heard of this before. Will try to learn about this and see if this solves my problem